# unknown attribute error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a devise authenticated login and a contacts module...the idea is that, users have multiple contacts...  the contacts class has name and number as its attribute...but when I try to create a contact, it throws an error stating `"unknown attribute: user_id"` ... where am I going wrong?? I tried adding `user_id` in contact model...but still getting the error...help would be much appreciated..

Contact model:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :name, :number, :user_id
end
```

contact controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def show
    @contacts=current_user.contacts
    @contacts.save
  end

  def index
    @contact=current_user.email_id
  end

  def create
 #  @contact=contacts.new
    @contact= current_user.contacts.build( :name=> params[:name] , :number=>params[:number] )
    @contact.save
    redirect_to contacts_show_path
  end

end
```

Comment: > c=User.last
> a=c.contacts.build( :name=>"bharath", :number=>12345) in rails console also i get the same error

Comment: Just to double check, does your Contacts table have a user_id column?

Comment: no..it does not have a user_id column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `has_many :contacts` to your user model as well as add the "user_id" column to your contacts migration file.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end
```

Comment: rails generate migration AddUser_idColumnToUsers user_id:integer ??

and then i should do a migrate??

Comment: i had problems with adding the field..i jus created a new model with the fields and it worked..

Comment: I have a question to Catfish,..... why we add has_many is Contact model?... I think we need to add it in User model , as a user has many contacts.